# Get data about IP addresses

Tags: java, php, html, geolocation, ip

I have around 30K IP address(IPv4) in a MySQL Database.

I want to get information related to these IPs like

Country
City etc.

I have tried IP-to-Country Databases which are not very accurate and are wrong for many IPs.

Web APIs do not let these many IP queries and also maybe inaccurate.

I want to have accurate information . **(atleast Country should be accurate)**

I have Java at Backend , PHP/HTML5 for display

Please Help .

Comment: You could probably get the country, but you're not going to get anything else to accurate.

Comment: I've used Maxmind GeoIP in the past, it's worked pretty well. http://www.maxmind.com/app/city If you want more accuracy, you're going to have to pay $$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think maxmind is probably the defacto geoip database.  They [offer a free one](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolite) that is 99.5% accurate on a country level and 78% accurate on a city level.

They have both php and java libraries.
http://www.maxmind.com/app/ip-location

Comment: I don't know about "very" accurate. They claim "Over 99.5% on a country level and 78% on a city level for the US within a 40 kilometer radius.", but it has worked well in my area.

Comment: The country information is accurate execept for some "international" internet providers (as e.g. AOL, do they still exist???). AOL gave users american IP addresses and/or just proxied data through them. For most customers the country information should be correct. You'll also get the ISP. You can filter IPs from "special" ISPs and handle them differently if needed.

Comment: I am using [link]http://firestats.cc/wiki/ip2c which is wrong many times i check manually . I will now try with Maxmind geoip. But i have seen online sites which get exact information even with lat/longitudes and ISPs .

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works like **magic**...........

**Key and Secret:**

```
private final String key = "86b780aec0cee918718d7eb2fa084df412771c17";
private final String secret = "d3e3fa0a1fc6a35ac02aa591ed32ecaa750df9a7";
```

**Method to Create the Session:**

```
public void xmlCreateSession(){

             String createSession = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"+"\n"+"<request>"+"\n"+"<token>"+"</token>"+"\n"+"<key>"+this.getKey()+"</key>"+"\n"+"<secret>"+this.getSecret()+"</secret>"+"\n"+"</request>";
            firingUrl = "https://int.yumzing.com/index.php?func=sessionCreate";
            // firingUrl = "http://199.87.235.147/sessionCreate";

          //firingUrl = "https://int.yumzing.com/sessionCreate";

             String tempCreate = postData(firingUrl, createSession);
             this.getMToken(tempCreate);
             System.out.println("getToken value "+this.getToken()); 

    }
```

**Method to Find the IP:**

```
public void xmlUserIp(){

           String userIp = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"+"\n"+"<request>"+"\n"+"<token>"+this.getToken()+"</token>"+"\n"+"</request>";

           firingUrl = "https://int.yumzing.com/index.php?func=userIp";

           String tempIp = postData(firingUrl, userIp);
           this.getMIp(tempIp);
           System.out.println("getToken value "+this.getIp()); 

    }
```

**Method to get Info based on IP:**

```
public void xmlUserLocation(){

        this.xmlUserIp();
        System.out.println("With in xmlUserLocation-"+this.getToken()+" "+this.getIp());

           String userLocation = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"+"\n"+"<request>"+"\n"+"<token>"+this.getToken()+"</token>"+"\n"+"<ip>"+this.getIp()+"</ip>"+"\n"+"</request>";
           firingUrl = "https://int.yumzing.com/?func=userLocation";



          System.out.println("With in xmlUserLocation-"+this.getToken()+" "+this.getIp());
           String tempLoc = postData(firingUrl, userLocation);
           System.out.println("In xmluserLoc"+tempLoc);
           this.getMLocation(tempLoc);

           System.out.println("getToken value "+this.getCountry()); 
           System.out.println("getToken value "+this.getState()); 
           System.out.println("getToken value "+this.getCity()); 
           System.out.println("getToken value "+this.getLatitude()); 
           System.out.println("getToken value "+this.getLongitude()); 
    }
```